# No Secure Boot Option

Tags: boot

I have an Asus A55A series laptop, intel 3 core, 4gb memory, REPLACED MOTHERBOARD, and upgraded from pre-installed windows 8.1 to 8.2, and now i cannot find any secure boot option. When i go to the BIOS and look for the secure boot option for me to disable in order to run Ubuntu. So if anyone can tell me how to make secure boot appear or fix it that'd be great. It doesn't boot Ubuntu on start up, which is why i'm thinking it has to do with the secure boot option.

Answer (score 2):

According to your notebook's [manual](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/K55VM/E7187_eManual_K55VM_K55VS_Z104.pdf) you do have UEFI but no Secure Boot (which was [added](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Secure_boot) in UEFI 2.2).

Try to install Ubuntu without disabling Secure Boot.

If you have any problems booting or installing Ubuntu, please update your question with more information about your problem (for example the errors you're getting).